# then is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, imagemin

I'm running the following code in my node.js project. I've required "imagemin" and "imageminGifsicle". I've getting the following error

> }).then(files => {
>      ^
>   TypeError: imagemin(...).then is not a function

Do I have not used promises in my projects before. Do I need to include them to use .then ?

```
imagemin(['export/sample/out.gif'], 'export/sample/out2.gif', {
 plugins: [
  imageminGifsicle({optimizationLevel: 1})
 ]
}).then(files => {
  console.log(files);
  console.log("finished");
}).catch(err => {
  console.log("ERR:"+err);
  throw err;
});
```

Comment: How did you install imagemin? It has a dependency on    "promise.pipe" and should support the .then chaining based on its docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.then` is Promise related and [`imagemin` added this only on 5.0.0](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin/releases/tag/5.0.0).

What version of it are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes- you can choose the library you prefer for promises, and use "then" function with promises. In this case you are using imagemin:

```
const imagemin = require('imagemin');
const imageminMozjpeg = require('imagemin-mozjpeg');
const imageminPngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
```

[imagemin on GitHub](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin)

For using Promises, you can read some of the specifications and info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and  [here on stackoverflow](http://here)